# clippy complains "avoid complex blocks"

Tags: rust-clippy

After an update of rust from 1.68 to 1.76 I have strange complaints from clippy.

```
    error: in a `match` scrutinee, avoid complex blocks or closures with blocks; instead, move the block or closure higher and bind it with a `let`
   --> *******:153:102
    |
153 |       pub async fn func(&self, content: &[u8]) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    |  ______________________________________________________________________________________________________^
154 | |         //some code here 
155 | |
156 | | 
159 | |     }
    | |_____^
    |
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#blocks_in_conditions
```

There are no "match" or "if" at all. The curly brackets show just the function body.

Comment: seems it is a bug which described here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/12281